# scala class member function as UDF

Tags: scala, udf

I am trying to define a member function in a class that would be used as UDF while parsing data from a json file. I am using trait to a define a set of methods and a class to override those methods.

```
trait geouastr {
  def getGeoLocation(ipAddress: String): Map[String, String]
  def uaParser(ua: String): Map[String, String]
}

class GeoUAData(appName: String, sc: SparkContext, conf: SparkConf, combinedCSV: String) extends geouastr with Serializable {
  val spark  = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
  val GEOIP_FILE_COMBINED = combinedCSV;

  val logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass)
  val allDF = spark.
    read.
    option("header","true").
    option("inferSchema", "true").
    csv(GEOIP_FILE_COMBINED).cache

  val emptyMap = Map(
    "country" -> "",
    "state" -> "",
    "city" -> "",
    "zipCode" -> "",
    "latitude" -> 0.0.toString(),
    "longitude" -> 0.0.toString())

  override def getGeoLocation(ipAddress: String): Map[String, String] = {
    val ipLong = ipToLong(ipAddress)
    try {
        logger.error("Entering UDF " + ipAddress + " allDF " + allDF.count())
        val resultDF = allDF.
        filter(allDF("network").cast("long") <= ipLong.get).
        filter(allDF("broadcast") >= ipLong.get).
        select(allDF("country_name"), allDF("subdivision_1_name"),allDF("city_name"),
          allDF("postal_code"),allDF("latitude"),allDF("longitude"))
          val matchingDF = resultDF.take(1)
          val matchRow = matchingDF(0)
        logger.error("Lookup for " + ipAddress + " Map " + matchRow.toString())
        val geoMap = Map(
          "country" -> nullCheck(matchRow.getAs[String](0)),
          "state" -> nullCheck(matchRow.getAs[String](1)),
          "city" -> nullCheck(matchRow.getAs[String](2)),
          "zipCode" -> nullCheck(matchRow.getAs[String](3)),
          "latitude" -> matchRow.getAs[Double](4).toString(),
          "longitude" -> matchRow.getAs[Double](5).toString())
      } catch {
        case (nse: NoSuchElementException) => {
          logger.error("No such element", nse)
          emptyMap
        }
        case (npe: NullPointerException) => {
          logger.error("NPE for " + ipAddress + " allDF " + allDF.count(),npe)
          emptyMap
        }
        case (ex: Exception) => {
          logger.error("Generic exception " + ipAddress,ex)
          emptyMap
        }
      }
  }

  def nullCheck(input: String): String = {
    if(input != null) input
    else ""
  }

  override def uaParser(ua: String): Map[String, String] = {
    val client = Parser.get.parse(ua) 
    return Map(
      "os"->client.os.family,
      "device"->client.device.family,
      "browser"->client.userAgent.family)
  }

  def ipToLong(ip: String): Option[Long] = {
    Try(ip.split('.').ensuring(_.length == 4)
      .map(_.toLong).ensuring(_.forall(x => x >= 0 && x < 256))
      .zip(Array(256L * 256L * 256L, 256L * 256L, 256L, 1L))
      .map { case (x, y) => x * y }
      .sum).toOption
  }
}
```

I notice uaParser to be working fine, while getGeoLocation is returning emptyMap(running into NPE). Adding snippet that shows how i am using this in main method.

```
    val appName = "SampleApp"
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    val geouad = new GeoUAData(appName, sc, conf, args(1))

    val uaParser = Sparkudf(geouad.uaParser(_: String))
    val geolocation = Sparkudf(geouad.getGeoLocation(_: String))

    val sampleRdd = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val json = sampleRdd.filter(_.nonEmpty)

    import spark.implicits._


    val sampleDF = spark.read.json(json)

    val columns = sampleDF.select($"user-agent", $"source_ip")
    .withColumn("sourceIp", $"source_ip")
    .withColumn("geolocation", geolocation($"source_ip"))

  .withColumn("uaParsed", uaParser($"user-agent"))
  .withColumn("device", ($"uaParsed") ("device"))
  .withColumn("os", ($"uaParsed") ("os"))
  .withColumn("browser", ($"uaParsed") ("browser"))
  .withColumn("country" , ($"geolocation")("country"))
  .withColumn("state" , ($"geolocation")("state"))
  .withColumn("city" , ($"geolocation")("city"))
  .withColumn("zipCode" , ($"geolocation")("zipCode"))
  .withColumn("latitude" , ($"geolocation")("latitude"))
  .withColumn("longitude" , ($"geolocation")("longitude"))
    .drop("geolocation")
      .drop("uaParsed")
```

Questions:
1. Should we switch from class to object for defining UDFs? (i can keep it as singleton)
2. Can class member function be used as UDF?
3. When such a UDF is invoked, will class member like allDF remain initialized?
4. Val declared as member variable - will it get initialized at the time of construction of geouad?

I am new to Scala, Thanks in advance for guidance/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, switching from `class` to `object` is not necessary for defining `UDF`, it is only different while calling the `UDF`.
2. Yes, you can use class member function as `UDF`, but first you need to register the function as an `UDF`.

   spark.sqlContext.udf.register("registeredName", Class Method _)
3. No, other methods are initialized when calling one `UDF`
4. Yes, the class variable val will be initialized at the time of calling `geouad` and performing some actions.

Comment: I have tried #2 -     spark.sqlContext.udf.register("geolocation", geouad.geolocation _). I am seeing null pointer exception @ logger.error("NPE for " + ipAddress + " allDF " + allDF.count(),npe